# Text-mining/word correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation, text-mining

I'm trying to make text mining or rather word correlation work in R.

The bigger picture of what I'm trying to do is, I query the entire exported OpenStreetMap database for all features that are within a specific distance to various longitude-latitude locations. So far, this is working like a charm and I have gotten to the point where I have a data frame column of type `character` that contains all features in that specific distance where one row represents one longitude-latitude location. The data frame column can be found in [this csv](https://pastebin.com/XrDmz822) and a catalogue of all possible features can be found in [this csv](https://pastebin.com/8KwAy9F0).

My next step would now be to categorise the locations depending on their surrounding features. To do this, I would like to use a text mining/word correlation algorithm that is able to create categories based on features that are often present at the same locations.

**So in short:** I have a column of type `character` (words separated by commas) where one row contains all features that are within a certain vicinity to a longitude-latitude location. Based on those surrounding features I would like to categorise my locations relying on correlating features.

I have tried [findAssocs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-7/topics/findAssocs) from the tm package, which unfortunately doesn't work for neither type `list`, `data.frame` nor `character`.
I have also found [this wonderful documentation](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/265713_cbef910aee7642dc8b62996e38d2825d.html) that guides through basic text mining in R. The problem here is that it seems like I would have to convert each row of my data frame column into a document to prepare a corpus for further processing. While this might be feasible for my test case of 61 locations, it won't be so much for my final analysis of several tens-of-thousands of locations.

Can anyone prod me in the right direction here? Preferably, without relying on 3rd party software like 'rapidminer'. Having everything in one R script would be a lot better for my use case.

Thank you in advance. If you require any additional information, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question seems interesting, and you could get a lot of help here, but you need to provide a [mcve] and a bit more detail about what is the rule to categorize your locations based on the features containes in your column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a step-by-step guide to convert data from my format to one that can be used for text mining. The guide can be found [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/256588_57b585da6c054349825cba46685d8464.html). This does answer my problem for now.
I do apologise for the post.